# PHP Select database rows from current month and display them with foreach()

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

I am making a payment system for my website, and i need a way to select everything from a database where the month and year is identical as the current month and year. My date is formatted as dd/mm/yyy or 
01-01-2010 for example.

After this is done, i need to display all results with a foreach() loop. How could this be done? I've tried using the LIKE function in the mysql_query, but it just outputs an error.

Here are some code i've come up with:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

$today = date("d-m-Y"); // Output something like 21-10-2014 for finding matching rows
    $today_compare = substr($today, 2, 8);

$fetch_donate = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `shop_payments` WHERE date LIKE '%today_compare%");
```

Comment: Are the dates stored in your database in that format? as dd/mm/yyyy? Or are they php timestamps?

Comment: you NEED to provide your MySQL statements! and any other relevant code

Comment: They are stored in that format also (im from Denmark). The timezone is UTC.

Comment: @cmorrissey Just added some code

Comment: You should STRONGLY consider storing your dates/times in the Database in appropriate date, dateetime, etc. fields. If you are using string fields and have a mix of formats your are not going to find a reasonable solution.

Comment: change `date LIKE '%today_compare%")` to `date LIKE '%$today_compare'")`, note the `$` and the closing `'`

Comment: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. It's awful and is being removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices. Always be absolutely **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will have severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: "My date is formatted as dd/mm/yyy" well, I guess it's not too late to fix that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will give you an answer, based on the assumption that you can change your date field in the database to actually be a date data type field.  I am also going to assume you change the column name to a non-reserved word `date` to something like `payment_date`. this is just a good habit to get into - not naming database objects the same as reserved words.

The query could be as simple as this:

```
SELECT *
FROM `shop_payments`
WHERE `payment_date` LIKE CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), '-', MONTH(NOW()), '%')
```

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly :) I changed it to payment_date and changed the mysql columns to DATE instead of CHAR :)